# Unable to resolve "startActivity()" when trying to use it from RecyclerView's onClickListener()

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and trying to implement the RecyclerView. Please forgive me if the question is redundant but I could not find my answer anywhere else. So, I'm finally posting my question.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class QueriesAdapter extends         RecyclerView.Adapter<QueriesAdapter.QueryViewHolder> {
    private List<Query> list;
    private Context mContext;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class QueryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        protected TextView questionTextView;

        public QueryViewHolder (View view)
        {
            super(view);
            this.questionTextView = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_question);

        }

    }


    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public QueriesAdapter(Context context, List<Query> myDataset) {
        mContext = context;
        list = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public QueriesAdapter.QueryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        QueryViewHolder vh = new QueryViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(QueryViewHolder holder, int position)      {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.questionTextView.setText(list.get(position).mQuery);
        holder.questionTextView.setTag(holder);

    }

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            QueryViewHolder viewHolder = (QueryViewHolder)v.getTag();
            int position = viewHolder.getPosition();
            Query q = list.get(position);

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Answer.class);
            i.putExtra("QueryId", q.id);
            i.putExtra("question", q.mQuery);
            i.putExtra("answer", q.mAnswer);

            startActivity(i);
//This line is showing error that it cannot resolve startActivity() function, I think that I did not pass the context properly. 
//Anyway, help me on this.

        }
    };

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Now, this is a part of my MainActivity which I used to instantiate the QueriesAdapter Class(a Custom Adapter)

```
mAdapter = new QueriesAdapter(this, list);
```

Comment: Try calling the startActivity with mContext

Comment: Call it like `mContext.startActivity(i)`

Comment: Thank you it worked. But may you please tell me why it was not working before

Comment: @HarshitKumar startActivity is method of context. Activity extends context. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use mContext to start a method which is default in the Activity try with `mContext.startActivity(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `mContext.startActivity(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement in the following way. Define a click listener in `RecyclerView` adapter class so that event can be consumed in corresponding `Activity` or `Fragment`. This helps making the events to handle easier

```
public class ListViewNotifyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <...>{

//defining a click listner
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
//usual methods and variables goes here

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }
//interface for click 
public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
//view holder
public static class NotificationObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView txtEventAlias;
        TextView txtTime;
        TextView txtLogMessage;
        public NotificationObjectHolder(View viewItem){
            super(viewItem);
            txtEventAlias=(TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtEventAlias);
            txtTime=(TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
            txtLogMessage=(TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtLogMessage);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getPosition(), v);
        }
}
}
```

Now in the class which you have implemented the RecyclerView do like the following

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((ListViewNotifyAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(
                new ListViewNotifyAdapter.MyClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

                        showAlert(position);
                    }
                });
    }
  void showAlert(int position){
      //action for the item click
   }
```